# Publishing page on CME is different from that on XPM about default publishing rules for pages. Is it design?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, broker

I'm trying to confirm a page publishing behavior on XPM and CME.

Setup:

- Dummy Schema (which have no schema fields.)
- News Schema
- News Summary
- Component Template (CT) with both set:

  - `Published as a Dynamic Component`
  - `Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly`
- News Detail CT with just:

  - `Published Embedded on a Page`
- News Summary List CT with just: (This CT is to query the broker for matching a criteria and then return the News Summary Component Presentations to the page.)

  - `Published Embedded on a Page`
- News Page Template (PT)
- News Summary CT, News Detail CT is linked to News Schema.

setup image is below.
[image: a]

***First***, I publish a News Summary Page (use News PT) which use a Dummy component used News Summary List CT on CME.

***Second***, When I publish a News Detail Page (using News PT) which uses only a News Component used News Detail CT on **CME**, a News component used News Summary CT (News Summary DCP) is **not published**. So News Summary DCP is not appearing on a News Summary Page. 
I think the above behavior is by design in SDL Tridion?.

And I understand it is possible to change above design by developing Custom Resolver.

***Third***, When I create a News Detail Page (using News PT) which use only a News component used News Detail CT on **XPM** (Experience Manager) and click Finish Editing (by clicking `Finish Editing`, a page is auto-published), a News component used News Summary CT (News Summary DCP) is also **published**. So the News Summary DCP is appearing on a News Summary Page.

In summary:
Publishing the page through the CME appears different from publishing through XPM using default publishing rules for pages.

Is it by design or am I mistakek (for example, configuration)?

**UPDATE**

Thank you to answer my question. I understand clearly.

I confirm that the component **is not published** if the component **is not edited on XPM**.

And the component **is published** if the component **is edited on XPM**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of all that you describe is correct and by design, let me try to summarize and clarify a bit. The interesting parts happen in your #2 and #3 steps, so let me start there:

`#2` News Detail Page contains Embedded Component Presentations based on News Schema. When you Publish a Page, all Embedded Component Presentations are Published as part of that Page. If that Page would also contain a Dynamic Component Presentation, then that DCP is also Published separately. But in your case it only contains Embedded CPs, so indeed, by design your News Components will not be published to the Broker (automatically).

`#3` this is where the magic happens, since when you edit a News Component, you noticed now it did get Published. Why that is, is actually very simple. When you edit a Component inline in XPM, and click Finish Editing, it is not the Page that gets Published, but the Component which you edited (read changed) that gets Published. Only when you would have added or removed a CP to the Page, the Page itself would get Published.

So now let us look at what happens when you Publish a Component. A Component basically cannot be Published, what Tridion does when you select a Component for Publish is the following:

1. It will Publish any Page (that has been Published before) where that Component is on with a Embedded Component Template.
2. It will Publish that Component to the Broker as a Dynamic Component presentation with any linked Component Template that is set to be Published as a Dynamic Component.

So the result of your editing action in XPM in your case is that both #1 and #2 will occur, the Page itself will be Published, and your DCP gets Published.

Now for the solution, I think the best solution is indeed as you describe, write a Custom Resolver that will trigger Publishing the DCPs of the News Components on your Published Page.

Another option is, to just have the Author always Publish the News Component manually. But a Custom resolver is probably more user friendly.

*Note: Seeing that you don't intend to place the News Summaries on a Page, you can uncheck `Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly` from your News Summary Component Template. That will prevent people from accidentally using the CT on a Page. And the above described behavior will remain the same.*

## update

I have no clue regarding your sorting issue, mind you I also don't understand fully what you mean with "not sorted adequately". Maybe you can edit and update your question to clarify that a bit more. Or even perhaps remove it from this question and handle it in a separate (new) question.

Comment: Dear Bart Koopman. Thank you to answer my question. I understand clearly the above behavior. After clicking "New Page" Button, editing components and clicking "Finish Editing" Button, the component and the page is published. So if the component is not edited on XPM,  I confirm that the component is not published . Thank you very much. And I have still one question related to the above question. Please read "UPDATE".

Comment: OK. I update my question to clarify that a bit more. Please just a moment, Sorry.

Comment: Dear Bart Koopman. I remove it from this question and handle it in a separate (new) question. Thank you.

Comment: I handle it in new question. please refer to the following site.                                                               'Different Behavior (about Sort order) between the DCP published by clicking Finish Editing on XPM and the DCP published on CME'